# CSS Dropdown not Working in Mobile Browsers

Tags: html, css, web, google-web-designer

I used CSS drop down based on the Tutorial given in this link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp
but it doesn't work on Opera Mini and some other mobile browsers.
Please give me solution to modify the css given in the above tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `:hover` & `:focus` pseudoclasses in your CSS. `:hover` does not exist on mobile devices.

So

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

becomes

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content,
.dropdown:focus .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```